# How can I use HTML5 and JavaScript File API to cumulate loaded filesize?

Tags: javascript, input, hidden, html5-filesystem

I'm completing my website in HTML5 and JavaScript, and was wondering if there was a way I could use the new HTML5 `FileSystem` API to cumulate the various loaded file file-sizes as visitors go through the site. I could use PHP, but this idea I got seems more practical and easier to manage.

I'm reading the size that can be obtained through HTML5 with something as simple as :

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" />
```

(in HTML) and

```
$('#myFile').bind('change', function() {
    alert(this.files[0].size);
});
```

(in JavaScript)

so, I'm thinking to approach this as follow :

- use CSS to set the input to `display:hidden` since it seems I must use an input
- send a variable `theFile` in the hidden input (don't even know if I can do that)

  ```
  var theFile = "http://www.myHost.com/mySite/myFile.jpg";
  ```
- replace the

  ```
  alert(this.files[0].size)
  ```
- with something like

  ```
  fileSize = this.files[0].size
  ```

Any help or experience shared will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: fyi, unfortunately the HTML5 filesystem API is a bit of a non-starter - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: hehe yeah i admit, but if I dont try i'll never learn wont I ?

check my website, you'll see I'm not completely new to this, I'm just being humble out of respect for the real programmers out here...

Comment: sadly i just answered my own first question with the following information i just found : 

*The file input type creates a field through which users can upload files from their local computer or network. The VALUE attribute specifies the name of the initial file, but it is typically ignored by browsers as a security precaution.*

Comment: May be you interest this: [ajax-file-uploader](https://github.com/psinetron/file-ajax-uploader)